Discontinuous functions convolution
Suppose we have these function:

I am trying to find their convolution.Since they are both discontinuous when you use the sliding window technique to find the convolution , depending on where t is the integral changes for example:
Lets take try to find from $-2<-t<2$ or $-2<t<2$.Part of $h(t)$ will be inside $x(t)$.However depending on the t,same parts of $h(t)$ can be under or over different parts of $x(t)$ and because it is discontinuous there isnt a general formula which describes $h(t)$ so you cant even break off the integral.How can I solve this problem out??

Hint: Convolution is linear.

Ah okay I got it.So I need to calculate 9 convolutions?

Two should suffice to make your life easier. Any more than that will just make it harder.
